# function CopyToClipboard ()

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который копирует в буфер текст из `input`.
Подскажите, как можно сделать выборку из элементов копирования.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyToClipboard () {
        var input = document.getElementById ("toClip1");
          var textToClipboard = input.value;

       var success = true;
        if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
            window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", textToClipboard);
        }
        else {
                // create a temporary element for the execCommand method
            var forExecElement = CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard);

                    /* Select the contents of the element 
                        (the execCommand for 'copy' method works on the selection) */
            SelectContent (forExecElement);

            var supported = true;

                // UniversalXPConnect privilege is required for clipboard access in Firefox
            try {
                if (window.netscape && netscape.security) {
                    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege ("UniversalXPConnect");
                }
                    // Copy the selected content to the clipboard
                    // Works in Firefox and in Safari before version 5
                success = document.execCommand ("copy", true, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                success = true;
            }

                // remove the temporary element
            document.body.removeChild (forExecElement);
        } 
    }
    function CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard) {
        var forExecElement = document.createElement ("div");
            // place outside the visible area
        forExecElement.style.position = "absolute";
        forExecElement.style.left = "-10000px";
        forExecElement.style.top = "-10000px";
            // write the necessary text into the element and append to the document
        forExecElement.textContent = textToClipboard;
        document.body.appendChild (forExecElement);
            // the contentEditable mode is necessary for the  execCommand method in Firefox
        forExecElement.contentEditable = true;

        return forExecElement;
    }
    function SelectContent (element) {
            // first create a range
        var rangeToSelect = document.createRange ();
        rangeToSelect.selectNodeContents (element);

            // select the contents
        var selection = window.getSelection ();
        selection.removeAllRanges ();
        selection.addRange (rangeToSelect);
    }

</script>
<input id="toClipboard1" value="какой-то текст для буфера"/><button id="toClip1" onclick='CopyToClipboard ()' src="img/wifi.png" >Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

вдруго кому понадобится еще **Вариант решения.**

```js
function CopyToClipboard(elID) {
    var textToClipboard = document.getElementById(elID).value;
   

            var success = true;
            if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
                window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", textToClipboard);
            }
             else {
                    // create a temporary element for the execCommand method
                var forExecElement = CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard);

                        /* Select the contents of the element 
                            (the execCommand for 'copy' method works on the selection) */
                SelectContent (forExecElement);

                var supported = true;

                    // UniversalXPConnect privilege is required for clipboard access in Firefox
                try {
                    if (window.netscape && netscape.security) {
                       netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');
      netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserRead');
     // netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite")

                    }

                        // Copy the selected content to the clipboard
                        // Works in Firefox and in Safari before version 5
                    success = document.execCommand ("copy", true, null);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    success = false;
                }
                
                    // remove the temporary element
                document.body.removeChild (forExecElement);
            }

           /*  if (success) {
                alert ("The text is on the clipboard, try to paste it!");
            }
            else {
                alert ("Your browser doesn't allow clipboard access!");
            } */
        }

        function CreateElementForExecCommand (textToClipboard) {
            var forExecElement = document.createElement ("div");
                // place outside the visible area
            forExecElement.style.position = "absolute";
            forExecElement.style.left = "-10000px";
            forExecElement.style.top = "-10000px";
                // write the necessary text into the element and append to the document
            forExecElement.textContent = textToClipboard;
            document.body.appendChild (forExecElement);
                // the contentEditable mode is necessary for the  execCommand method in Firefox
            forExecElement.contentEditable = true;

            return forExecElement;
        }

        function SelectContent (element) {
                // first create a range
            var rangeToSelect = document.createRange ();
            rangeToSelect.selectNodeContents (element);

                // select the contents
            var selection = window.getSelection ();
            selection.removeAllRanges ();
            selection.addRange (rangeToSelect);
        }
```

```html
<br> <input class="js-copytextarea" id="id_1" value="какой-то текст для буфера1"/><button onclick="CopyToClipboard('id_1')">Copy</button> <br>
<br> <input id="id_2" value="какой-то текст для буфера2"/><button onclick="CopyToClipboard('id_2')">Copy</button> <br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```