# getElementById выбор элементов

Tags: javascript

Как сделать выбор элемента?

```
var input = document.getElementById ("id_1");
```

у меня несколько id элементов с названиями `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_n`;
как можно сделать выбор этих элементов с последующей передачей `value=`

```
var textToClipboard = input.value;
```

---

**UPDATE**

@cyadvert: *с разрешения автора вношу правку в вопрос*

.

Как оказалось, автор не совсем корректно поставил вопрос.
После обсуждения стало ясно, что вопрос нужно перефразировать.

Есть несколько полей с кнопками у каждой. При нажатии на кнопку надо взять содержимое соответствующего поля и занести в буфер.

**HTML**

```
<br> <input id="id_1" value="какой-то текст для буфера1"/><button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy</button> <br>
<br> <input id="id_2" value="какой-то текст для буфера2"/><button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy</button> <br>
<br> <input id="id_3" value="какой-то текст для буфера3"/><button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy</button> <br>
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: используй класс а не id

Comment: суть не в том что использовать, а как именно это можно сделать?

Comment: так вот и ответ: ставишь всем нужным элементам один класс, и по нему выбираешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо передавать `id` элемента в функцию:

HTML

```
<br> <input id="id_1" value="какой-то текст для буфера1"/><button onclick="CopyToClipboard('id_1')">Copy</button> <br>
```

JS

```
function CopyToClipboard(elID) {
    var textToClipboard = document.getElementById(elID).value;
    window.clipboardData.setData("Text", textToClipboard);
}
```

Comment: 'function CopyToClipboard(elID) {
    var textToClipboard = document.getElementById(elID).value;
  function CopyToClipboard () {
      var input = document.getElementsByClassName ("id_1");
            var textToClipboard = input.value;
            var success = true;
            if (window.clipboardData) {
                window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", textToClipboard);'
  Функция в функции получится но нет увы

Comment: ответ изменен...

Comment: То что нужно! Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Присвой им, например, класс `ids`, после чего получи массив класса `ids` с помощью `document.getElementsByClassName("ids")`, затем перебором делай с ними что хочешь.

HTML

```
<input class="ids" id="id_1">
<input class="ids" id="id_2">
<input class="ids" id="id_3">
```

JS

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("ids");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    //Действия и инпутами
}
```

Comment: вот не знаю почему. но если изменить ById на ByClassName. Последующий скрипт не работает.  var success = true;
            if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
                window.clipboardData.setData ("Text", textToClipboard);
            }

Comment: "не работает" - компьютер выключается, компьютер взрывается, маленький гномик вылезает из компютера и говорит: "Не работает."?

Answer (score 0):

Предложения насчет класса - самые разумные.
Однако если это по каким-то причинам не возмжно, то посоветую что-то типа такого:

Прокручиваетесь сквозь все инпуты до последнего и работаете с каждым по отдельности

```
var n=1;
var moreInputs = true;
do {
    theInput = document.getElementsById("id_" + n);
    if (theInput != 'undefined') {
        [тут делаете все необходимое с инпутом]
    } else {
        moreInputs = false;
    }
    n++;
} while(moreInputs);
```

*Замечание*: `id` инпутов должны существовать по порядку.
Т.е. если у Вас, скажем, отсутствует `id_4`, то код остановится, и `id_5`, `id_6` ... `id_n` обработаны уже не будут.

Comment: `код`var n=1;
var moreInputs = true;
do {
    theInput = document.getElementById("id_" + n);
    if (theInput != 'undefined') {
        var textToClipboard = input.value;
    } else {
        moreInputs = false;
    }
    n++;
} while(moreInputs); `код`   Боюсь что то я не понимаю или делаю не так но он по прежнему не передает value от input дальше в код. вот Html код `код` <br>
    <input id="id_1" value="какой-то текст для буфера1"/><button  onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy</button>
<br>
   `код`         Извините за оформление. Я просто не пойму как тут править его

Comment: Попробуйте исправть на `var textToClipboard = theInput.value;`

Comment: и еще, Вы же понимаете, да, что с таким кодом у вас `textToClipboard` будет всегда содержать `value` последнего обработанного инпута?...

Comment: опишите, что Вы хотите сделать с содержимым всех тех инпутов, что найдете?

Comment: мне все не нужны. Есть код копирующий в буфер из input. в нем Один элемент мне нужно что бы можно было определить элемент и взять у нужного элемента его value

Comment: Так нужен только один??? Но в вопросе Вы пишете во множественном числе... "сделать выбор этих элементов"... Так что. нужно обратиться к ОДНОМУ конкретному элементу и вытащить его конкретное содержимое?

Comment: так что, возле каждого input будет стоять кнопка? и при нажатии на кнопку надо копировать в буфе содержимое этого поля?

Comment: Именно. Список из элементов и у каждого свой input с текстом. Id будут фиксированные. у каждого элемента но в примере с буфером там всего 1н элемент и вопрос в том как научит его определять нужный и брать верный! вот сам код [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487418/function-copytoclipboard]

Comment: В таком случае я советую Вам поменять вопрос, потому что он совсем не соответствует тому, что вы хотите...

Comment: на что посоветуете поменять? увы я php учил

Comment: позволите мне поменять от Вашего имени?

Comment: да прошу. Требуются какие-то от меня действия?

Comment: изменения внесены...

Comment: вроде подтвердил

Answer (score 0):

Полагая, что кнопка идёт сразу за полем ввода, можно воспользоваться свойством элемента `previousSibling` для получения элемента прямо перед ним. План: слушать события нажатия на кнопки и получать `value` предыдущего элемента.

Чтобы поместить значение в буфер, кроссбраузерно, есть библиотеки, напр., [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/). В примере ниже значение для копирования просто выводится в `div`:

```js
function copyMe(e) {
  var textToCopy = e.currentTarget.previousSibling.value;
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Скопировано: " + textToCopy;
  // ... place it to clipboard
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('copy');
for( var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", copyMe);
```

```html
<br><input type="text" id="id_1"><button class="copy">Copy</button>
<br><input type="text" id="id_10"><button class="copy">Copy</button>
<br><input type="text" id="id_100"><button class="copy">Copy</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

**Старый ответ на вопрос до редактирования:**

Если `id` унифицированы, то можно пробежать по всем имеющимся `<input>` и, если начало их `id` это строка "id_", то прихватить их `value`:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

function check() {
  var i, result = [];

  for( i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if( inputs[i].id.substr(0,3) === "id_") result.push( inputs[i].value);
  }

  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = "Итого: " + result.join(', ');
}

document.getElementById("btn-check").addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Stac"   id="id_1">
<input type="text" value="koverf" id="id_5">
<input type="text" value="low"    id="id_77">
<input type="text" value="на в счёт"  id="trololo">
<br><button id="btn-check">Собрать</button><div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: не сбор не нужен. нужно что бы каждая кнопка давала определенный value из своего input  в буфер

Comment: @Данил обновил ответ.